# Port forwarding not working correctly

Tags: port-forwarding

I am trying to my web server available from outside my net. I have set a static IP for my PC:

[image]

And I have also set port forwarding:

[image]

It works fine if I use my local IP address (192.168.0.240) from a host inside my network, but if I use my public IP it does not work at all. Any ideas? I have disabled my firewall (`ufw` in my case because my host is running Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Do you use your public IP address from the inside of your network? or from the outside? Compare [this](https://superuser.com/a/609932/432690).

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense. I am going to check it out.

Comment: Ah, you are a life saver. It was that! Thanks a lot :D. Please pot your answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: At the moment I'm busy. I won't mind at all if you answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

1st off, Who is your ISP? From that point are they providing you with their own Internet wan box or do you have your own? If you have one provided you will have to log into theirs and DMZ your main routers IP address. That's just one way of doing it. There's several ways to resolve your issue. It all depends on the way your intranet/internet is setup.

Comment: I have a domestic router. My ISP is Telewifi S.l. But if I enable DMZ it will leave open all ports.

Comment: Hello. I have ATT fiber and use their Router from the ONT. Its then connected to my MAIN router that I use for everything else. I was able to log into their router and set the DMZ only to My MAIN router's IP (BTW which has it own Firewall) and port forward withing my router. Everything works great.